# At what point did my former primary residence become an income property?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, taxes, rental-property, primary-residence

Last year we bought another house (and moved into it as our primary residence).  Rather than sell our previous house, we opted to keep it and rent it out.

Since the tax treatment for rentals is different than for primary residences (namely, a whole lot more can be deducted if it's a rental) I need to know what the cut-over point is.

I *imagine* that it's no earlier than the closing date on our new house, and no later than when the tenants signed the rental agreement, but when exactly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The day you placed the ad putting up for rent, or if you used a broker, the day you signed that contract. Of course, if for whatever reason, you listed/advertised it before vacating, the day it was available to a willing tenant is the day. 
Good luck - Read that to mean "I wish you the best of tenants"